# DataStax Cassandra C# Driver and TTL

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm looking to use the DataStax Cassandra C# Driver (1.0) with the Linq implementation. Example: https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/2.0/src/samples/Cassandra.Samples.Linq/Program.cs

I was wondering if there's any way to set the TTL when using this approach.

Comment: I see that context.GetTable<X>().Insert(new X{...}).SetTTL(60).Execute() is available. Is that the recommended approach?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Anyways I'd suggest staying away from the EntityFramework approach as that's not the best model of working with C*.

Comment: I know...was surprised it's there. But it's easy to explain to most dev not familiar with Cassandra, and gets the job done with far less friction than EF ever can :P